# when i want to redirect after setting a coockie its says HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my controller for login:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login, string ReturnUrl = "/Admin/pages/index")
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (loginRepository.IsUserExist(login.UserName, login.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName, login.RememberMe);
            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Username and password is incorrect");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

and I redirect it after setting the cookie to Admin Area, but it gave me the error:

> "HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized"

My Admin Area Controler:

```
[Authorize]
public class PagesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(pageRepository.GetAllPage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was at web.config

have to add the following line in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="Website" loginUrl="/Account/login" timeout="43200"></forms>
</authentication>
```